Does moving /home require any special considerations
/home is somewhat of a system directory but sub directories within it probably contain the bulk of user data. If I wish to move non system material to a recently added drive, it can be done with various cp commands and a few mv commands to perform the substitution in the end.  (mv /important /oldimportant; mv /newimportant /important).
Would there be anything different when attempting to mv /home /oldhome;mv /newhome /home  In order to perform such a move, you've got to be using an ID on the system.  All IDs on the system have a directory within /home from which configurations unique to each ID are referenced.  That material is going to be in use when the move takes place.

Home contains the snap directory.

I do not use snaps and do not know if moving just data gives issues. But  I move all data, but not /home into another partition either same drive if larger or second drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2464944&p=14048909#post14048909

@David - Why would the snap directory be an issue, so long as nothing about snap was being altered during the few milliseconds of the move command?

This Ubuntu documentation about moving the /home folder to its own partition is comprehensive.

If you want to move /home or /home/zeye/ move it to an ext4 formatted partition. The /home/zeye/ includes hidden configuration files and folders that may require specific permissions that will not be contemptible with an NTFS or ExFat partition for example.

Also see this answer

See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml, or read man hier.
It explains where things go. Departing from the Standard places one at risk of becoming broken and unsupportable.


/home is somewhat of a system directory

No, it IS,

but sub directories within it probably contain the bulk of user data.

so put those on a 2nd disk and not /home/
Benefits:

/home contains hidden directories that benefit from a quick boot
if /home is on the same disk as the system it will not break boot. In the old days a hdd with /home might not have been ready for the system to reach /etc/fstab so it could not find /home... it will the create a new one with empty settings. root on a quick sdd, and /home on a 5400rpm can be bad (maybe that was pre-systemd though :) )
your data on a different partition can be exFAT or NTFS so you can use it with windows.
you can also share this partition with other users, or segment the data for different users.

The system is already set up to be able to do this: see ./config/users-dirs.dirs.

Would there be anything different when attempting to mv /home /oldhome;mv /newhome /home In order to perform such a move

create a new partition using gparted from a live session and then shrink / to something like 40Gb (is enough for /, /home and snaps) or 20Gb-ish if no snaps used. Then make a 2nd partition with the remainder. Name it something, Could be /data if you want.
sudo chmod 775 /data 
sudo chown zeye:zeye data

and you own that partition
mv the directories in /home/zeye/ to this new partition.
Then open your filemanager, remove the dirs from /home and add the new ones on /data/
